# core graphics in iphone

Tags: iphone

I m learning core graphics in iphone. I got basics about how to draw. I want to know how can we put any graphics ,say a circle, in a loop so we can move it ? like in JAVA, we use repaint method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, another solution might be to make the element that's moving a separate `UIView` / `CALayer`, and animate its position using Core Animation (in which case, the looping and tweening are handled by the system). Highly recommend you start with [Getting Started with Graphics and Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Graphics_iPhone/index.html).

Comment: what I want to do is simple. see I've draw a circle (100,100,50,50) of size n now just want to move the circle from left to right(at maximum X).

Answer (score 2):

On an iPhone, you repeatedly call a view's setNeedsDisplay method using an NSTimer or CADisplayLink.  The OS then calls your view's drawRect method to repaint the circle, and/or redraw any other core graphics drawing needed.

You don't loop in an event driven framework.  You tell the OS to repeatedly call you back, and then exit your code and wait.